# A High School Math Question dealing with coordinate geometry

Tags: geometry

This to me has never been seen before:

> Square $ABCD$ with side length $5$. Name any point $20$ units from from point $D$ , $E$. From every random point inside the square $F$ rotate $E$ about $F$ $120$ degree counterclockwise. *Compute Area  of the region formed by all of the image points of the rotation*

I tried to draw a pic according to the description in the problem:
[image]
**Can anyone explain what the problem is asking and give a comprehensible answer?**
PS: This is not a question of my own. I did get this from my teacher. So I think there shouldn't be any problem solving this problem.

Comment: Let's keep the swearing down to a minimum (which is zero, in this case).

Comment: Without really understanding "image points of the rotation", I would think that your graph is way off. If $E$ is $20$ unit away from $D$, it should be much further away from the square. In particular, it shouldn't land within the square if I read your problem correctly.

Comment: This one should be correct.

Comment: Are you quoting the problem word-for-word? Because it doesn't make sense to me. "Every random point"? "All of the image points"? Please check that you have it exactly right!

Comment: I did, I know this question itself has grammar problem. But it is a legitimate problem from a NYCIM contest if you heard of it

Comment: I think the question is trying to say: let $E'$ be the image of $E$ under rotation by $120^\circ$ around $F$; what is the area of the locus of $E'$ as $F$ varies over $ABCD$?

Comment: I just took E prime as an example

Comment: But you are partially right. I think too it may be asking for the combined area of all the possible sectors.

Comment: You have infinitely many options for choosing $F$ and $E$. Each way of choosing $F$ and $E$ produces a point $E'$. The problem asks: If we graph *all possible E'*, what area will that graph have?

Comment: @chubakueno: The wording of the question suggests to me that $E$ is fixed, and we are looking at all possible $E'$ generated by varying over $F$.

Comment: @EricStucky It is likely because of the vague wording, but I don't think that all choosings of points $E$ would result in a shape with the same area.

Comment: If you have AutoCAD or something like that it might really help with this problem. It's not too difficult I think just draw a picture and then work out the geometry from there. Might require that you do an integral or two, but they're nothing more than trig substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's position the square conveniently.  Let $A=(-5,0)^T, B=(-5,5)^T, C=(0,5)^T, D=(0,0)^T$.  It is not clear whether $E$ ranges over the whole circle centered at the origin with radius $20$ or is some point on that circle.  I will take $E=(20,0)^T$.  It should be clear how to generalize the question.  We are asked to let $F$ range throughout the square, so let $F=(x,y)$.  The we evaluate $\vec{FE}$, rotate it $120^\circ$ around $F$ and find the area of the locus as $F$ varies.  $FE=(20-x,-y)^T$ and $E'=\begin {pmatrix}x\\y \end {pmatrix}+\begin {pmatrix} -\frac 12&-\frac {\sqrt 3}2\\\frac{\sqrt 3}2&-\frac 12 \end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix}20-x\\-y \end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}-10+\frac 32x+\frac {\sqrt 3}2y\\10\sqrt 3-\frac {\sqrt 3}2x+\frac 32y \end {pmatrix}$

Now we can see that the choice of a particular $E$ does not matter to the size of the locus.  Changing the location will change the constants $-10, 10 \sqrt 3$, but not the size of the region created.  Let $E'(D)$ be where the rotation sends $E$ when $F=(0,0)^T$, then we get a square with corners $$E'(D)\\
E'(D)+(-\frac{15}2,\frac {5\sqrt 3}2)^T
\\E'(D)+(-\frac{15}2+\frac {5\sqrt3}2,\frac {5\sqrt 3}2\frac 52)^T\\
E'(D)+(\frac {5\sqrt3}2,\frac {15}2)^T$$
, side $5 \sqrt 3 \approx 8.66$and area $75$
A figure is below.  The square doesn't look quite like one because the scales don't match.  $E'(A)$ is the position $E$ is moved to when $F$ is at $A$.

[image]

Comment: The rhombus in the graph doesn't look placed right to me. In particular, the $y$-coordinate of $E'(D)$ should be sitting closer to 17 than 7.

Comment: @EricStucky:  Right you are.  I found a couple errors and corrected them.  This looks much better.  Thanks.